# Prove or disprove that Every bounded linear functional on a Banach space is a quotient map?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Prove or disprove that Every bounded linear functional on a Banach space is a quotient map?

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}$  and $f:X\to \mathbb{K}$ be a functional on $X$.
If $f$ is nonzero then it is surjective. Also $X/\ker{f}$ is linearly isomorphic with $\mathbb{K}$. Let $g:\mathbb{K}\to X/\ker{f}$ be a linear isomorphism. Then $g\circ f:X\to X/\ker{f}$ is a linear surjective mapping.
Please help me to find mistake if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your argument never used the fact that $X$ is a Banach space (or that $f$ is bounded).

It is incomplete: you showed that it is a linear quotient map, but you still need to show that the quotient norm is equivalent to the standard norm on $\mathbb K$.

Comment: Please help me to show that the quotient norm is equivalent to the standard norm on $\mathbb{K}$. @tomasz

Comment: @Jana: Exercise: **every** norm on $\mathbb{K}$ is equivalent to the standard norm.  (Hint: if $|\cdot|$ is the standard norm, and $\|\cdot\|$ is another norm, think about how $\|x\|$ relates to $|x|$ and $\|1\|$.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Strictly speaking, one needs to also prove that it is actually a norm and not a seminorm.

Comment: @NateEldredge As $\mathbb{K}$ is finite dimensional over itself any two norms are equivalent on it. Any linear transformation on a finite dimensional space is continuous .  So $g$ is continuous and $g\circ f$ is also continuous.

Answer (score 2):

It can be answered by following way:
Let $f:X\to \mathbb{K}$ be a non zero bounded functional on a Banach Space $X$. As it is non zero functional, it is surjective . Also $\mathbb{K}$ is a Banach space.  By open mapping theorem $f:X\to \mathbb{K}$ is an open mapping. We know that Every surjective open and continuous map is a quotient map. Therefore $f:X\to \mathbb{K}$ is a a quotient map.